# Currency Converter in Python

Tags: python

I am learning python and I have a task to write a program that converts currencies. It needs to support those currencies: BGN, USD, EUR, GBP with those rates:

Rate     USD      EUR     GBP
1 BGN   1.79549 1.95583 2.53405

There is automatic test engine that will input value to convert + entry currency + target currency. The output should be a number converted by the rates.

I thought I could use a dictionary and do something like the code below. Would you help find why it is not working and find the elegant solution?

```
value = float(input())
in_curr = input()
out_curr = input() 

dict = {'BGN': 1, 'USD': 1.79549, 'EUR': 1.95583, 'GBP': 2.53405}

def currency_converter (value,in_curr,out_curr):
    return((dict[in_curr] / dict[out_curr]) * value)
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Is there some input/output which isn't meeting your expectations?

Comment: You never call the function. `print(currency_converter(value, in_curr, out_curr))`

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? What output do you get, and what output do you want?

Comment: I'd expect Input: 20, USD, BGN and Output: 35.91 BGN.

Comment: You haven't said why your code doesn't work. What output do you get from your code? Please edit your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you didn't use **print** function
You can view the result directly by using IPython (i.e. Jupyter Notebook)

Your function looks fine and I would suggest you to eliminate the function like

```
print((dict[in_curr] / dict[out_curr]) * value) #python 3
```

or change the function into:

```
def currency_converter (value = value,in_curr = in_curr,out_curr = out_curr):
```

Then use `print(currency_converter())` to display the final result

Comment: Thank you @Luke ! Simple print was exactly what I needed :).

Answer (score 0):

This app converts currencies from USD,EUR etc to Naira using dictionary:

```
 currency = {"USD": 580, "GBP":700, "CAD": 400, "EUR": 650, "CHF": 450, "YEN":200}


print('''Welcome to your currency converter App

         For USD conversion to Naira type USD,
         For GBP conversion to Naira type GBP,
         For CAD conversion to Naira type CAD,
         For EUR conversion to Naira type EUR,
         For CHF conversion to Naira type CHF,
         For YEN conversion to Naira type YEN,*''')


signs = input('Type the currency you want to convert to: ').upper()
amount = float(input('Enter the amount you want to convert: '))

if signs =="USD" or signs =="GBP" or signs =="CAD" or signs =="EUR" or signs =="CHF" or signs =="YEN":
    conversion = amount * currency[signs]
    print("The conversion of {}{} to naria is NGN {}".format(signs,amount, conversion))
else:
    print("You have entered a wrong value for the conversion type, {} is not among the list for conversion".format(signs))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution using list instead of dictionary

```
currency = [580,700,400,650,450,200]
symbols = ["USD", "GBP", "CAD", "EUR","CHF","YEN"]


print('''Welcome to your currency converter App

         For USD conversion to Naira type 0,
         For GBP conversion to Naira type 1,
         For CAD conversion to Naira type 2,
         For EUR conversion to Naira type 3,
         For CHF conversion to Naira type 4,
         For YEN conversion to Naira type 5,*''')


signs = int(input('Type the currency you want to convert to: '))
amount = float(input('Enter the amount you want to convert: '))

if signs ==0 or signs ==1 or signs ==2 or signs ==3 or signs ==4 or signs ==5:
    conversion = amount * currency[signs]
    currency_symbols = symbols[signs]
    print("The conversion of {}{} to naria is NGN {}".format(currency_symbols,amount, conversion))
else:
    print("You have entered a wrong value for the conversion")
```